# JToolBar custom button error

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

I'm working on my own component and i'm trying to add a custom button to my admin view that calls a task.

```
In view.html.php 

protected function addToolBar() {
JToolBarHelper::custom('addApplicationToDB', 'generic.png', 'generic.png', 'Add Test Application'); 
JToolBarHelper::custom('jobApplications.addApplicationToDB', 'generic.png', 'generic.png', 'Add Test Application'); 
}
```

At the bottom of my default.php i've added

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />     
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="jobApplications" /> 
<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

Although I don't really understand what it does.

My controller is in admin/controllers/jobApplications.php

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class jobapplicationsControllerjobapplications extends JControllerAdmin {
public function addApplicationToDB() {
    echo "Add Application pressed!!!";
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
            echo "Add Application pressed!!!";
    $db = JFactory::getDBo();
...
```

The errors i keep getting is " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'boxchecked' of undefined "

I'm stumped... I have no idea what is wrong or where to go about fixing it.

You can find the full code : https://github.com/gicadin/com_jobApplications

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? I just ran the code you have on github on my local 3.4 dev copy and I'm not seeing anything.

Comment: Sorry I did not commit the faulty code. I was getting the error in the chrome console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a custom button only needs this string in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
```

The button posts to the controller and there you need to setup the method that this button targets.

So your code code for the addToolbBar method should look like this

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('controllername.taskname', 'generic.png', 'generic.png', 'Add Test Application');
```

So lets say your controller name is "jobApplications" and your task in the controller is "addApplicationToDB" then it should look like this

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('jobApplications.addApplicationToDB', 'generic.png', 'generic.png', 'Add Test Application');
```

In the controller file that is in the controllers folder you need to add the following method

```
    public function addApplicationToDB()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries
        JSession::checkToken() or die(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

        // make sure it is a user
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        if ($user->id)
        {
            // do your thing
        }
        return;
    }
```

Here I have a [demo component on github](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component) that has a [custom button implementation](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component/blob/master/admin/views/looks/view.html.php#L146) take a look also at the [controller](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component/blob/master/admin/controllers/looks.php#L42) and other scripts related.

Check the following [url](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_toolbar_for_your_component) for more info, hope this helps

Comment: I apologize for not answering sooner. I've tried your solition, but i'm getting the exact same error as before. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" 

So i've decided to try add a custom button in the core joomla file just to see if it works. 

I've added a JToolbarHelper::custom('article.testButton, '', '', 'test button'); to administrator/components/com_content/views/view.html.php and 
public function testButton() { .. } to administrator/components/com_content/controllers/article.php

Still no luck!!! I feel like im nearly there but missing something

Comment: Here I have a [demo component on github](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component) that has a [custom button implementation](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component/blob/master/admin/views/looks/view.html.php#L146) take a look also at the [controller](https://github.com/namibia/demo-joomla-3-component/blob/master/admin/controllers/looks.php#L42) and other scripts related.

Comment: I was still missing the <form action="..." id="adminForm"> after adding <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />. I also had another form that used the admin id which was why it took so long to debug. Your demo application helped a lot, with more than just this problem but I've also picked up a few more things from it. Thanks for putting it together, i appreciate the effort!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe here you need to register the task.  In your components controller class, the one located in either the front or back end folder root, add the following line inside your display method:

```
$this->registerTask('jobApplications', 'jobapplications.addApplicationToDB');
```

This should register the method with Joomla core.  I'd also remove the hidden input field with the name attribute "controller" and value of "jobApplications."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With custom toolbar buttons in Joomla 3, try adding:
    
or
    
in your adminForm (edit view) to avoid javascript error.
As always, hit control+u to view the markup and activate your firebug console to watch for errors.

Comment: {input name=boxchecked value=0 or value=1}